# Vue.js local template variables

Tags: templates, variables, vue.js, local

I have a needed to create a local variable in my Vue template to shorten references to an otherwise long object `$v.form.text`, as shown in the example below:

```
<input 
    :class="{ error: !$v.form.text.required }"
    v-model.trim="$v.form.text.$model" 
/>
```

I would like to be able to access the `$v.form.text` nested object in my template as simply `text`.

```
<input 
    :class="{ error: !text.required }"
    v-model.trim="text.$model" 
/>
```

There is usually a lot more code than in the example above, justifying creating a temporary variable, but the problem is the same as shown.

> Note: I have already solved this, please see answer below, and simply want to document the solution for others who might be searching for the same.

Answer (score 7):

I just had this same problem and thought of another hack/workaround... Note I haven't tried this yet but should work.

Just use v-for with a single inline array containing your long expression, i.e.

```
<span v-for="item in [my.big.long.expression.item]">{{item.foo}} {{item.bar}}</span>
```

:)

Comment: This was the first thing I thought of but I was hoping there would be something better that was built in. Like `v-var` or something that I somehow overlooked.

Answer (score 6):

I could of course just use a computed function to do this, but in some cases it is not possible, such as when you're inside a `v-for` and want your computed to refer to the loop's iterator variable. In such cases, my solution is as follows:

```
<div :set="text=$v.form.text">
    <input 
        :class="{ error: !text.required }"
        v-model.trim="text.$model" 
    />
</div>
```

For those that may now be thinking, "Hey, I didn't know there was an undocumented `:set` in Vue", **there isn't**.

What I'm doing here is relying on the fact that Vue will evaluate the JavaScript of any bound attributes and I just chose to invent an unused attribute called `:set`.

As a reminder, a bound attribute is one that is prefixed with a `:` or `v-bind:`. The JavaScript expression inside the double quotes will be evaluated in the context of the current component and the `item` variable will still be available outside of the `v-for` in which it is being set. So, it's not a local variable, as such, rather, it's a locally assigned, component scope variable.

**Make sure** to add this variable to your variable declarations in the data hook.

```
data() { return { 
    text: '' 
}}
```

Here is a link to a CodePen showing this pattern at work https://codepen.io/pbastowski/pen/PXqjPG?editors=1100

Comment: In case this pattern is used inside a `v-for` AND that some event handlers (e.g. `@click`) use the variable, the solution from LMK is necessary.